# Spinner Angular material não funciona em chamadas síncronas

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Tenho uma chamada síncrona `new SyncRequestClient().post<HistoricoModel,Response>(solrRequest, request);` e preciso que seja criado um spinner para essa chamada. Aparecer antes de ser feita a chamada e sumir depois da chamada utilizando o componente do AngularMaterial `<mat-progress-spinner>` ou `<mat-spinner>`, porém não funciona, o spinner nunca aparece.

código html:

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="spinnerVisible"></mat-spinner>
```

component.ts

```
public spinnerVisible: boolean = false;

 public sendGetDocumentosAllPages(pesquisa, tipo) {
    this.spinnerVisible = true;
    response = new SyncRequestClient().get<Response>(solrRequest);
    this.spinnerVisible = false;
    return response;
}
```

A consulta demora a ser executada, porém o spinner nunca aparece

Comment: Esse seu codigo esta inteiro sincrono

Comment: Sim, ai sendo assim não é possível adicionar um spinner. Ou será que tem como? Eu acho que não funciona porque só pode uma ação por vez, é isso ?

Comment: ele não funciona porque esse codigo sincrono é praticamente instaneo , pra funcionar vc tem que transformar em asincrono pra esperar a chamada

Answer (score 2):

Como te disseram nos comments, o teu codigo está sincrono - isto quer dizer: ele nao vai esperar por que nada acabe, simplesmente vai correr os statements do script até ao seu fim.

para ser *asincrono* (que é como quem diz, esperar que os statements retornem até passar para o proximo statement) terás que trocar a função para `async function` e usar o `await`:

```
public spinnerVisible: boolean = false;

async sendGetDocumentosAllPages(pesquisa, tipo) {
  this.spinnerVisible = true;
  const syncReqCli = new SyncRequestClient();
  const response = await syncReqCli.get<Response>(solrRequest);
  this.spinnerVisible = false;
  return response;
}
```

isto, claro, assumindo `new SyncRequestClient().get` retorna uma Promise.